# Composer : how to add a dependency without network connection?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

My profesionnal network block internet access. Some month ago I download the Silex framework from an archive (which contains composer.json file) and the composer.phar one's, then I transfer them on my desktop throught HDD.

My composer.json that I customized:

```
{
    "name": "user/silex",
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.2"
                , "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev"
                , "doctrine/dbal": "2.2.*"
                , "symfony/security": "~2.3"
                , "symfony/security": "~2.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Portal\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, my autoload customization too.

**Today** I want to add the `monolog/monolog` package, so I manually import it from an other computer.

I place it into my vendor folder, I add the following line to my composer.json file:

```
, "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0.0"
```

I run on the console:

```
php composer.phar dumpautoload
```

It outputs:
    Generating autoload files

Then it stop without error, but the monolog namespace doesn't appear into my `/vendor/composer/autoload_*.php` files.

What did I miss?

Comment: I have a feeling that the best way to do this would be to specify your own custom repository and download the actual repositories to your computer and then reference your local repositores. I don't know exactly how to do that though, or if its possible - https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Comment: @edmondscommerce You get it, I have to create an *artifact repository*.

Comment: Cool, that looks like the way forwards. Would be good for you to do a detailed answer on exactly how to do it for the benefit of others hitting this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [edmondscommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543455/edmondscommerce)'s comment I found the solution:

I update my main *composer.json* file with an [**artifact**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact) respository (and I disable the packagist one):

```
{
    "name": "user/silex",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "artifact/"
        }, {
            "packagist": false
        }
    ], "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.2"
                , "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev"
                , "monolog/monolog": "1.*"
                , "doctrine/dbal": "2.2.*"
                , "symfony/security": "~2.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Portal\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I put a folder called `artifact` according to the url put in the *composer.json* file.

I create into this folder a zip called *monolog-monolog-1.8.zip* with the library I want to add.

Then just launch a `composer update` command!

Be carefull, zip's root must contain a *composer.json* file, and this *composer.json* file must contain a version!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to create a custom repository, you can also run `composer install` (or `composer update`) on a copy that is on a network-connected computer. Then you can copy over the newly added and extracted component into the vendor folder on the machine without internet access. Note that you also need to copy `vendor/composer/installed.json` to let composer know that the new package has been installed. Once you have copied all these files, you can run `composer install` on the machine without internet access and it will not try to install anything and dump autoload files.