# Cannot make composer install work offline

Tags: composer-php, satis

I am trying to set up Composer to work without internet access. I have set up a server in the local network with a Satis configured repository with the following configuration file:

```
{
  "name": "private/composer",
  "homepage": "http://<some_ip>:9500",
  "repositories": [
    {"type": "composer", "url": "https://packagist.org"}
  ],
  "require-dependencies": true,
  "require": { ... },
  "archive": {
    "directory": "offline",
    "format": "zip"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
}
```

After running

```
$ ./satis/bin/satis build ./satis.json ./mirror
```

Everything works, I get my `./satis/mirror/offline` directory filled up with `.zip` files of the packages I am mirroring from `packagist.org`.

In my Composer, project, I added the following sections to the `composer.json` configuration:

```
{
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://<some_ip>:9500"
    }],
    "config": {
        "secure-http": false
    },
    ...
}
```

I tried to run `composer install` then and I get an error about Composer not begin able to access `https://packagist.org/packages.json`. Why is it trying to do that? How can I make this process work without internet access?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer : how to add a dependency without network connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378840/composer-how-to-add-a-dependency-without-network-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Composer does not disable access to packagist.org when you add custom repos. You can disable it with the following config:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist.org": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like I should've read the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#disabling-packagist-org) better, eh? Thank you very much! Haven't tested it yet, but it surely works