# How to install composer packages without internet access?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Currently, I am trying to migrate a development environment for a Laravel project from a local environment with Internet access to a new development environment that does not have internet access due to our company policies. However, I am stuck at trying to prepare the Laravel project as I'm running the `composer install` command as it tries to download the packages from packagist.

I've tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378840/composer-how-to-add-a-dependency-without-network-connection) but the project currently has more than 30 packages and this method would involve editing each json to include a version as well as the dependencies of each package.

I have also tried to edit the composer.json to point to the path of the packages as mentioned [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) which would also have the same issue where I would need to manually specify the nested required packages as well.

Is there a way to setup the development environment which would not require Internet access while I already have the vendor files already?

Thanks.

[Edit] As mentioned in my original question, the solution that was suggested in the original question was too manual and require specifying each package and its version in the composer.json. If there were 30 dependencies and each one has its own dependencies, the original solution wouldn't be feasible as there will be too many packages to be done manually.

Comment: Copy the `vendor` in your pen drive.

Comment: trying the simple solution would have worked

Comment: Which simple solution are you referring to? Are you referring to just copying the vendor folder into the environment without internet access? Would I be able to run php artisan serve directly in that case?

Comment: @NicoHaase thats the question that I linked to which would involve editing each package's composer.json to include a version.

Comment: If that does not help, you should either think about using Satis as a proxy (which would need internet access) or asking the IT department how to handle this. Using a development environment without any internet access looks pretty unusable to me

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately, it's company policy to have no internet access

Comment: So, how do you write mails? How do you plan to check whether this question has new answers? Programming without internet access is pretty hard.....

Comment: The development environment doesn't have internet access, but we still have a local environment with internet access.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is to manually move the vendor folder to the server, and avoid running `composer install` there.

This is definitely not ideal and it requires you to have the same configuration both on your source enviroment (your local machine) and your destination environment (the server without internet).

By same configuration I mean the same PHP version and extensions

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote for this. It's absolutely the easiest way if you have to do this.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this solution and see